# Why is NAT networking no longer working under VMware Workstation Player 17?

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a VMware 17 installation with NATted Windows and Linux guests, a Mint host that has normally functioning network access, and none of the guests are able to load google.com. The Linux guests flash alternating notices that network access has been disconnected, and that network access has been established.

There are questions about why bridged VMware networking is not working, including some that are multiple years old. But I am not attempting bridged networking, or using Player 5.

This is new behavior since the last time I attempted to use networking, successfully, on a Windows 10 guest.

What should I be doing to re-enable NATted networking in the guests?

Comment: Also, VMware Fusion from the Mac next to my Mint box has been able to run networking from a new NATted Mint installation without issue that I have noticed.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the text. Which do you want? NAT or Bridged?

Comment: @DanielB Sorry, my bad. I want NATted networking, and just edited the title accordingly.

Comment: My answer will work for NAT and Bridged networking both. I have used Network Reset before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do something in the spirit of John's answer, attemptedly. (I could not follow his answer per se because it assumes menu choices that I do not see in Workstation Player 17.)

I shut down virtual machines, uninstalled VMware completely and all settings with it, then reinstalled VMware Workstation Player from a fresh download and, upon receiving warnings about inadequate system swap space, added the following at the end of `/etc/vmware/config`:

```
prefvmx.useRecommendedLockedMemSize = "true"
prefvmx.minVmMemPct = "100"
```

The latter, or some alternative (I was going off of https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/0-bytes-of-system-swap-space-is-available/td-p/2646467), addressed an onerous behavior of the guest starting up with a tiny swap space and swapping heavily and moving like molasses.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted if helpful?

Comment: I don't see your answer now. But I do not remember downvoting it?

Comment: I gave another answer with similar information so you may wish to follow up on your further question which you say I solved for you.