# Why is my VMware Workstation Player 17.0.2 installation not responding to reboot, retry, reinstall?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I posted [Why is NAT networking no longer working under VMware Workstation Player 17?](https://superuser.com/questions/1789959/why-is-nat-networking-no-longer-working-under-vmware-workstation-player-17) earlier and got instructions of basically "Retry, reboot, reinstall." (The host was running Linux Mint 21.0 and is now running 21.1, and I have not purchased a VMware license key.)

I uninstalled and reinstalled VMware Workstation Player, with the two lines to `/etc/vmware/config` added as per my answer, and Workstation Player worked for a couple of days before a recurrence of the complete network failure. I uninstalled again (the command at least for the second time was `vmware-installer -u vmware-player`; in both cases I opted for deletion of all VMware installation data), and tried to reinstall Workstation Player 17.0.2. The installer ran without apparent failure, but `vmplayer` segfaults every single time run from the command line, and does nothing discernible when started from a Cinnamon menu. (I have never subsequently seen vmplayer open a window when run.)

Do I want to run some other command besides `vmplayer`? How can I completely reset non-virtual-machine/non-virtual-disk installation and data for Workstation Player and start from a clean slate?

I noticed, when checking about whether there was a newer release for Workstation Player, that a DuckDuckGo search for "vmware workstation player" had a first search result of "VMware Workstation Player|VMware", and under it a "Download now" link to https://customerconnect.vmware.com/en/downloads/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/16_0 which offered Workstation Player 16.2.5. (I wonder if VMware is offering an older version while they're trying to patch 17.0.2? But 16.2.5 after an uninstall is behaving similarly.)

What should I do to get VMware Workstation Player working?

Comment: “ I wonder if VMware is offering an older version while they're trying to patch 17.0.2?” - This hasn’t happened

Comment: Back up your virtual machines.  Delete the VMs (they were backed up). Do a complete uninstall of VMware Player.  Restart.  Install VMware Player. Now do two things:  (1) Restore the existing VM and try it.  (2) Make a new VM and try that.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you.

Comment: @John I restarted between uninstalling and reinstalling and it appears to work now..

Comment: @ Christos Hayward  ...   I posted an answer for you and trust you will follow up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to get VMware Workstation Player working?

Do the following repair for the VM App.

> Back up your virtual machines. Delete the VMs (they were backed up).
>
> Do a complete uninstall of VMware Player.
>
> Restart. Install VMware Player
>
> Restore the VM and it should work.

You can try a new test VM if necessary.