# What is a version of VMware Workstation Player that will not have 17.0.2's recurrent network failure?

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I posted [Why is NAT networking no longer working under VMware Workstation Player 17?](https://superuser.com/questions/1789959/why-is-nat-networking-no-longer-working-under-vmware-workstation-player-17) earlier, and John's response was basically Retry, Reboot, Reinstall. He clarified on this or another question that the procedure he recommended was to be augmented by backing up, deleting, and reinstalling virtual machines as well as VMware Workstation Player.

I have for all but the last time succeeded in temporarily masking the symptom. Each previous time I have uninstalled VMware Workstation Player, rebooted, and reinstalled VMware Workstation Player, networking has worked again for a little while. Now after a fresh uninstall-reboot-reinstall networking is not presently working; N.B. this is after upgrading from Mint 21.1 to Mint 21.2.

What is a version of VMware Workstation Player that would fix the problem? Meaning not just offer temporary relief of the symptom, but correct the root problem. (I'm also thinking of porting the VM to VirtualBox, but I'd like to identify a working VMware solution if possible.)

Will all recent versions of VMware Workstation Player develop this networking failure, and if not, which version(s) won't?

Comment: You did all this, right? https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1008367

Comment: You might consider a trial version of VMware Workstation Pro V17.  I have had that running 24x7 since it came out and V16 before that and no network failures.   In fact I have had all versions back to 1 running with only occasional, correctable network failures.

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks for the Knowledge Base article link, will work through.

Comment: @John Thank you for pointing out the trial version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware broke networking in 17.0.1 and left it broken in 17.0.2, at least for bridged networking ([See related bridged networking thread in VMware discussions](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/Bridged-Network-not-Working/m-p/2958019)).

Recommended solution is to downgrade to 16.x.